# SQL Merge - Only insert where specific column has been updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-merge

I have a merge statement that looks like the below

```
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET then Insert
(ID,
Status, 
Read,
User,
ChangeDate)
VALUES
(Source.ID,
Source.Status,
Source.Read,
Source.User,
Source.ChangeDate)
...
```

I am currently using the ID, Status and ChangeDate to match source to target. Sometimes the ChangeDate can change without any actual changes being made to the row. What I need to happen is for my merge statement to run and only insert a new row if the Source.Status is not the same as the latest Target.Status based on the ChangedDate.

My current target table looks like the following

```
ID    Status    Read    User    ChangeDate
33    Read       Yes     76     01-Jun-2019
33    Closed     Yes     76     12-Jun-2019
33    Read       Yes     76     23-Jun-2019
```

My merge statement wants to insert the below row into this table

```
ID    Status    Read    User    ChangeDate
33    Read       Yes     76     24-Jun-2019
```

I don't want this to happen because although the ChangeDate has been modified, the Status is the same as the previous row (23-Jun-2019)

If my merge ran again and tried to insert the below row

```
ID    Status    Read    User    ChangeDate
33    Closed     Yes     76     30-Jun-2019
```

Then this would insert a new row as the Closed status is not the same as the previous Read status.

Appreciate any help with this, I can't think of any way of getting around it currently.

Thanks
Jessica

Tried to merge on multiple different columns

Comment: Hi, sorry I have added this now

Comment: Hi, does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the field ChangeDate to match the source, because of this that your merge are always insert

and about the update you can do like this:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND (trg.example_column <> src.example_column 
   OR trg.example_column_2 <> src.example_column_2) THEN UPDATE
   SET 
   [VERSION] = tgt.ChangeDate = GETDATE()
```